# how to use mongo $or with , when field doesn't exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find documents where one of the fields either has certain values, or doesn't exist. I have a query which works for checking the values, but I need to make it also check for the field not existing.

My mongo query is like this currently:

```json
{ "$and" : [
  { "productId" : { "$in" : [ 00000000 , 11111111 , 22222222]}} ,
  { "count" : { "$gte" : 1}} , 
  { "purchaseCount" : { "$gt" : -1}}
  ]
}
```

This returns documents when `purchaseCount > -1`; but the documents where field `purchaseCount` doesn't exists are not returned.

How can I return the documents where `purchaseCount` doesn't exists and if `purchaseCount` exists then consider `purchaseCount > -1` ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the MongoDB [exists operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/); it has a similar syntax to the $and operator you are already using, taking an array of sub-queries:

```json
{ "$and" : [
  { "productId" : { "$in" : [ 00000000 , 11111111 , 22222222]}} ,
  { "count" : { "$gte" : 1}} , 
  $or: [
    { "purchaseCount" : { "$exists" : false } },
    { "purchaseCount" : { "$gt" : -1 } },
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: instead of `$exists` I used `{ "purchaseCount" : null }`. it works too. Do you know how can I convert it to `Query` ? for ex  : `ds.find(classType).disableValidation()                      .field(PRODUCT_ID).hasAnyOf(ProductIds).field(COUNT).greaterThanOrEq(getCount())` how can I add the `$or` criteria here ?

Answer (score 2):

I did this in my sample dataset and it works.

DataSet :

```
> db.prod.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2dfdeceb47a04bfd4cf4"), "productId" : 0, "purchaseCount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2e0deceb47a04bfd4cf5"), "productId" : 11111111 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2f06eceb47a04bfd4cf6"), "productId" : 222, "purchaseCount" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2f0aeceb47a04bfd4cf7"), "productId" : 222, "purchaseCount" : 1012 }
```

Sample Query to find records with purchaseCount > 100
 (you can add your condition here purchaseCount >= -1) 
and if purchaseCount does not exits.

```
> db.prod.find({"$or":[{"purchaseCount":{"$gt":100}},{"purchaseCount":{"$exists":false}}]})
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2e0deceb47a04bfd4cf5"), "productId" : 11111111 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57be2f0aeceb47a04bfd4cf7"), "productId" : 222, "purchaseCount" : 1012 }
>
```

HTH

Comment: actual value needs to be checked first before checking if exists

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `exists` function in mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/